# How would i get this timer to stop once the game has finished?

Tags: c#

Hi i was looking for some help on how i would get this time to stop once the game has finished and also how to change it to minutes once it reaches 60 seconds, the code for the timer is as follows:

```
    int i = 0;
    private void tmrCounter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        lblTime.Text = i.ToString() + " Seconds";
    }
```

Comment: Are you using DispatcherTimer? And also, what platform is this?

Comment: sorry im new to this language, just trying to get my head around somethings. It is stored inside a label is thats any help

Comment: Is this Windows Forms?

Comment: yes it is in windows form Bryan, have you any idea on how this can be done

Comment: How did it work out for you? Did you try out my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can just call the `tmrCounter.Stop();` to stop the timer.

For the seconds to timer, you can use this:

```
   i++;

   var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);

   lblTime.Text = string.Format("{0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

Or if you want to show only the seconds if it's still less than 60 seconds, you can use this:

```
   i++;

   var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
   if (ts.Minutes < 1)
        {
         lblTime.Text = string.Format("{0} Seconds", ts.Seconds);
        }
   else
        {
         lblTime.Text = string.Format("{0} Minutes, {1} Seconds", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
        }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
Timer tmrCounter = new Timer();
```

You can start it with either:

```
tmrCounter.Start();
```

or

```
tmrCounter.Enabled = true;
```

You can stop it with either:

```
tmrCounter.Stop();
```

or

```
tmrCounter.Enabled = false;
```

Assuming the timer's interval is one second and your Tick event handler increments a counter that represents seconds, you could divide by 60 to report minutes:

```
int i = 0;
private void tmrCounter_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    string text = i.ToString() + " Seconds";
    if (i >= 60)
    {
        text = (i / 60).ToString() + " Minutes";
    }

    lblTime.Text = text;
}
```